# Error While Publishing to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database

I am trying to publish some changes to an Azure App Service including database migrations as well but I am experiencing following error does any have have any clue what's this about.
P.S The database user does not have sysadmin server role assigned.

```
1>Warning SQL0: A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target 
platform may experience compatibility issues with Microsoft Azure SQL 
Database v12.
1>Warning SQL0: Your permissions to see all objects in the server or 
database could not be verified.  The original error was:
1>The SELECT permission has not been granted on 'sys.sql_logins' for the 
'master' database. You must be a member of the 'loginmanager' role to access 
this system view. 
1>Reverse Engineer will continue the import process, and logins will not be 
imported.
1>The reverse engineering operation will attempt to continue anyway, but the 
resulting model might be incomplete, malformed, or incorrect.
1>Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5011, Level 14, State 2, 
Line 5 User does not have permission to alter database 'Iklikl_Staging', the 
database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows 
access checks.
1>Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
1>IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
1>           FROM   [sys].[databases]
1>           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
1>    BEGIN
1>        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
1>            SET TEMPORAL_HISTORY_RETENTION ON 
1>            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
1>    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to target SQL Azure.

[From this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272687(v=vs.103).aspx):

**To change a project’s target platform**

Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Properties. Click the Project Settings tab on the left to access the Project Settings property page.

The Target platform dropdown list in this page contains all the supported SQL Server platforms that a database project can be published to. For this procedure, select SQL Azure.

Comment: it's not a database project it's a MVC web application, I have been publishing successfully until I wrote Migrations for it. Is your answer still valid for it cause I don't see any DropDown containing Target platform in settings page.

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with you MVC application. They are all database related. If you have developed on local SQL and want to deploy to Azure SQL, then they are very similar but not the same thing. The process to migrate Azure SQL to on-prem SQL is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate

Comment: I am using code first approach with Entity and the error occurs while trying to execute the script in the OP, I can create and alter and delete using the Sql Server Management Studio remotely but when I try to publish it through Visual Studio is breaks down throws the above mentioned errors, Now I am confused if it's something related to database permissions or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL user you are using for deployments isn't part of the `loginmanager` role.  `loginmanager` and `dbmanager` are two roles that are exclusive to Azure SQL.

Run the following against **master** (where `[user]` is your sql user):

```
ALTER ROLE loginmanager ADD MEMBER [user];
```

You can validate your user now is part of the correct role by running the following query:

```
select dp.name as db_role, dp2.name as db_user
from sys.database_role_members drm
join sys.database_principals dp on (drm.role_principal_id = dp.principal_id)
join sys.database_principals dp2 on (drm.member_principal_id = dp2.principal_id)
order by dp.name
```

The user may also need other permissions such as 'Alter', 'Select' and 'View Definition' which you can add by running the following example command against **your db** (where `[user]` is your sql user :

```
GRANT ALTER TO [user]
```

Here are the articles I used (defo read the first one, the last two compliment the info in it):

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/azure-dwh-part-12-permissions-roles-logins-and-users

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-schema-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15